# Importing PDF files into R and organizing the data

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so I would really appreciate some help!
I need to import a PDF document into R and organize it for data manipulation.

The PDF File: [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoCI9.png)

This is what I have:

```
library(pdftools)
field_data <- pdf_text("Q2 - WPA_points (Field).pdf") %>%
readr::read_table()
```

*First question, is there a better way to do this other than "read_table"? This gives me 122 obs of 1 variable, but I really just need the bottom part with is 117 obs of 7 variables. (When I use read_table2() it gives me 7 variables, but it seems to delete some cells)

Moving forward, with read_table, I have deleted the first 5 rows (unnecessary) and took out the column name, so it looks like this [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEOLb.png)

This is what I did:

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
field_data <- field_data[-c(1:5),]
colnames(field_data) <- NULL
```

This is where I'm stuck. I want to:

1. convert the first row "Event" "Class" "a" , etc. into the column names.
2. shift the rows that have "blank" under "Event" column to the right
3. fill in the blank spaces with the previous Event name

Final result should look like this:
[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPwM.png)

I hope I was clear, thank you very much for the help!